handling concurrent request
I am working in a payment gateway system using NestJS, Prisma ORM, and MySQL. I’m facing an issue with handling concurrent payout requests. When multiple requests are made concurrently, the system retrieves the same available balance from the user database, which results in incorrect payouts.
Problem:
Each request deducts the payout amount from the available balance.
Concurrent requests are picking up the same balance value, causing discrepancies in the final user balance.
What I’ve Tried:
Using a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE query to lock the user row while processing a request.
Prisma's $transaction to wrap the payout process and ensure atomicity.
async initiatePayout(payload: PayoutInitiateRequestDto, req: IRequest): Promise<PayoutResponse> {
  return await this.prisma.$transaction(async (prisma) => {
// Lock the user row for the transaction
const user = await prisma.$queryRaw<User[]>`SELECT * FROM "User" WHERE "id" = ${userId} FOR UPDATE`;

if (!user) {
  throw new Error('User not found');
}

const availableBalance = user[0]?.totalPayout;
const payoutAmount = +payload.amount;

// Check if the available balance is sufficient
if (availableBalance < payoutAmount) {
  throw new Error('Insufficient balance');
}

// External API call for payout process
const apiResponse = await this.externalApi.payout(payload);

if (apiResponse.success) {
  // Deduct the balance after successful payout
  await this.user.findOneAndUpdate({
    { id: userId },
     { totalPayout: availableBalance - payoutAmount },
  });
}

return apiResponse;

});
}

Select for update combined with transaction should work with plain mysql. What I don't know is how prisma implements theae exactly under the hood. What I do know that prisma has an extensive documentation on transactions and concurrency with sending money as one of the examples here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/queries/transactions Main point is: if you are using an ORM, try to stick with ORM features and not use raw sql statementsas the latter simply defeats the purpose of using ORM.

Implement a Conditional update:
Conditional update is a common optimistic approach to keep data consistent in the face of concurrent accessing, that is, consistency in the face of concurrency. For more about such a case, please refer to the Q&A here : Users can concurrently withdraw above their wallet balance by initiating multiple concurrent withdrawals
Note: The refactored code below may differ in syntax as I follow mongoose for Object modelling. However the logic for a conditional update remains the same, please apply the necessary syntactical corrections with respect to prisma in the given statement.
Please refactor the below code :
if (apiResponse.success) {
  // Deduct the balance after successful payout
  await this.user.findOneAndUpdate({
    { id: userId },
     { totalPayout: availableBalance - payoutAmount },
  });
}

as this :
// performing a conditional update to safeguard
// the possible write-write conflict
if (apiResponse.success) {
  // Deduct the balance after successful payout
  const newDoc = await this.user.findOneAndUpdate({
    { id: userId, totalPayout: { $gte : availableBalance  } },
    { totalPayout: availableBalance - payoutAmount },
  });

 // informing user for the needful action
  if (newdoc) {
    console.log(`Updation passed`);
  } else {
    console.log(
      `Updation failed - write-write conflict detected`
    );
    // please provide the code to revert the payout transaction here.
  }
}

The refactored code equipped with the conditional update checks for the sufficient balance at time of the update. If there is sufficient balance, then it is safe to proceed, otherwise, it means, there is a race condition has ben occurred, some other user session has already utilised the balance.
Under the event of aborting the update, the user must be informed accordingly, and the payout transaction which has already been taken place must be reverted as well.
Please also note that, if there had been concurrent session which utilised some balance, still there is enough left for the current transaction, then it is safe to proceed. Therefore this approach does not work in a pessimistic way so that even a possible concurrent transaction will be blocked.
